# Hiding noscript tags from search engines

Tags: html, noscript

I was looking for information on hiding noscript from search engines, this way help information on enabling JavaScript wouldn't end up added to the keyword density...

I’m thinking of using a different approach and wanted to get thoughts on it?

Looking at logs I noticed both google and bing have the word bot in it, so what about using an if statement using something asp to look at the user agent for the word bot in it and if it’s not there then continue to write the noscript tag?

This should eliminate it from both google and bing search results and would leave it available for other users who might have JavaScript disabled...

Comment: Modifying your html strictly for search engine bots is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using  is a good idea. I've heard that it is ineffective when the client is behind a JavaScript-blocking firewall - if the client's browser has JavaScript enabled the  tag won't activate, because, as far as the browser's concerned, JavaScript is fully operable within the document...

A better method IMO, is to have all would-be 'noscript' content hidden by JavaScript.

Here's a very basic example:

```
<body>

    <script>
        document.body.className += ' js-enabled';
    </script>

    <div id="noscript">
        some content
    </div>
```

And within your StyleSheet:

```
body.js-enabled #noscript { display: none; }
```

More info:

[Replacing  with accessible, unobtrusive DOM/JavaScript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/replacing-noscript-with-accessible-un/)

[Reasons to avoid NOSCRIPT](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/noscriptnomore.htm)

Comment: I understand what you're saying but wouldn't this only hide it from browsers (users) that have JavaScript enabled, the bots sent out by search engines to my knowledge have it disabled therefore it would still be visible to them, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need hide `noscript` *tags* from search engines. As far as we can know, they ignore them. They process the content of `noscript` *elements* as if the tags were not there. I presume you would want to hide that content.

There is no reasonable way to do that. Trying to send different content to search engines than to browsers is one of the main tricks that search engines try to detect, and they may punish for it.

The way to avoid having nonsensical content indexed as part of the page is to avoid including nonsensical content. There is normally no point in telling users to enable JavaScript. If the page is really an application that won’t work at all without JavaScript, then saying this inside `noscript` is OK, and when formulated properly, it does not pollute search engine indexes but provides useful additional content.

Comment: Bang on! My site is almost entirely JavaScript, a project that kind of got out of hand lol…


I don’t have that many pages yet and only recently launched the site, I have noscript pages specifically for someone who would have it disabled with instructions on how to identify browser type and then a link to instructions for each…  They were picked up and I didn’t want them to be indexed with my site but I guess ultimately you’re right it is extra content. That and being penalized doesn’t sound good.


Thanks